# luigi running external program can't locate bash file

Tags: python, bash, luigi

I am 'simply' trying to solve how to run an external program from luigi.
Utilising the ExternalProgramTask from luigi.contrib.external_program.

The luigi class is:

```
from luigi.contrib.external_program import ExternalProgramTask
import luigi

class PoincarreEmbedding(ExternalProgramTask):
    file_path = 'examples/tmp/3'

    def program_args(self):
        return [". embeddings.sh"]
```

Luigi runs and fails as it cannot find the file.

```
INFO: Running command: . embeddings.sh
ERROR: [pid 43886] Worker Worker(salt=404030211, workers=1, 
host=Roberts-MacBook-Pro.local, username=rhsmith, pid=43886) failed    
PoincarreEmbedding()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rhsmith/luigi/luigi/worker.py", line 194, in run
new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
File "/Users/rhsmith/luigi/luigi/worker.py", line 131, in _run_get_new_deps
task_gen = self.task.run()
File "/Users/rhsmith/luigi/luigi/contrib/external_program.py", line 98, in run
stderr=tmp_stderr
File "/Users/rhsmith/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/Users/rhsmith/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The '. embedding.sh' file is located in the same directory as where the module/task is run from.

Have been studying [this](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2017/03/25/luigi-externalprogramtask-example-converting-json-csv/) thread but to no avail. I am sure it simple :/

Comment: use an slash instead of an space in the last line of your class: `return ["./embeddings.sh"]`

Comment: No change. The [". embeddings.sh"] was to utilize the 'source' but I have tried multiple options now :/

Comment: I think its because the file isn't in the PYTHONPATH. I should probably learn about that. urgh